# Returning value from a shiny app in an interactive R session

Tags: r, shiny

I am making a little interactive widget using shiny. The purpose of the widget is not to create a stand-alone shiny web app. Instead, the idea is to run the widget in an interactive R session, to allow the user to interactively manipulate data from the session using a GUI. The output of the Shiny app should then be returned to the user session by the function.

The 'true' purpose of my widget is to interactively select data points on a plot, and return the values selected as the output of the function. However, to make a nice and simple REPREX, I have chosen a simpler scenario:

```
multiply_me <-
  function(number1) {
    require(shiny)
    
    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        selectInput('number2', label = 'Enter multiplication factor', choices = c(1, 2, 3)),
        textOutput('result')
        ),
      
      server = function(input, output) {
        output$result = renderText(number1 * as.numeric(input$number2))
      }
    )
    
  }
```

In the multiply_me function, the user can take a variable from the existing interactive session (`number1`), and run `multiply_me(number1)` to initiate the shiny widget. The widget then allows the user to select multiplication factors on the slider and view the result.

But how do I return the result of the calculation (`number1 * number 2`) to the interactive R session?

Comment: You could store the result in the global environment with `<<-`.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent. Though if it is at all possible, I would rather be able to return the value as a function in order to have greater safety and flexibility. With more complex real world applications, I would like to be able to (for example) run the app multiple times to generate different outputs, to see the effect of selecting different datapoints in the widget.

Comment: @DGreenwood did you get the 'true purpose' of your shiny project working? I'm developing something very similar, and have stuggled to find example code for how to return selected values from plots (I'm also new to shiny). If you could share anything instructive, or point me in the direction of resources you used, I'd be super grateful! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `stopApp`:

```
multiply_me <-
  function(number1) {
    require(shiny)
    
    runApp(list(
      ui = fluidPage(
        selectInput('number2', label = 'Enter multiplication factor', choices = c(1, 2, 3)),
        textOutput('result'),
        actionButton('ok','OK')
      ),
      
      server = function(input, output) {
        output$result = renderText(number1 * as.numeric(input$number2))
        observe({
          if(input$ok){
            stopApp(number1 * as.numeric(input$number2))}
         })
       }
    ))
  }

multiply_me(1)
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `stopApp` in a Shiny gadget:

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)

multiply_me <- function(number1) {
  
  ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("My Gadget"),
    miniContentPanel(
      selectInput(
        'number2', label = 'Enter multiplication factor', choices = c(1, 2, 3)
      ),
      textOutput('result')
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    result <- reactive({
      number1 * as.numeric(input$number2)
    })

    output$result <- renderText(result())
    
    observeEvent(input$done, {
      returnValue <- result()
      stopApp(returnValue)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$cancel, {
      stopApp()
    })
    
  }
  
  runGadget(ui, server)
}
```

The gadget opens in the RStudio viewer, and it has two buttons 'done' and 'cancel', so that you don't need to implement these buttons.